# Using Oracle Data Integrator 12c with Snowflake

Tags: oracle, cloud, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, oracle-call-interface

We successfully connected Oracle Data Integrator 12c from Oracle Cloud Infrastructure to Snowflake but when we run mappings which make use of the ODI Knowledge Modules, we are seeing batches of data being sent in small chunks via separate SQLIDs.  Does anyone have experience with using Oracle Data Integrator with Snowflake, cross cloud?  Any tips on how to process more records at once other than writing the records to a file first and loading the files?  That sort of defeats the purpose, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the Oracle Data Integrator works, but for most connectors to Snowflake, the connector SHOULD be creating files and loading them...usually behind the scenes.  Using a COPY INTO command or Snowpipe (both from blob storage) is the BEST way to get data into Snowflake.